# Finding the Coordinates of the selected text in a pdf using any pdf api for java

Tags: java, pdf

I want to extract the selected text from a pdf using any PDF Api for java. Using iText and PdfBox I am unable to do this task. So can any one help me out with this. I want to extract the selected text(which I will select by dragging my mouse over the text in pdf) and want to give comment to that selected text.

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know this kind of feature could be done using the excellent jpedal library..
So please refer to the following URL : http://www.jpedal.org/

HTH
Jerome